# JQuery Datatables plugin - attaching JSON to a Datatable with some conditions

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, datatables

In JQuery Datatables plugin, how do we attach JSON to a Datatable-enabled table when

1. there are some columns in Datatable-enabled table that are not in JSON
2. there are some columns that are in JSON, but we don't want to show it in the Datatable-enabled table

Example for #1

table columns

```
  person_id, first_name, last_name, age
```

JSON

```
  {{'person_id' : 1, 'first_name' : 'John', 'last_name' : 'Doe'}, ....}
```

Example for #2

table columns

```
   product_id, manufacturer_name
```

JSON

```
  {{'product_id' : 1, 'manufacturer_name' : 'Product X', 'manufacturer_code' : '144ctow4'}, ....}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DataTables accepts only `<table>` contents or javascript arrays. JSON must be instantiated and converted from an object into an appropriate array. If you have two data sources they must be combined before instantiating the DataTable with the appropriate information.

1)If you provide some context for your "there are some columns in Datatable-enabled table that are not in JSON" I can recommend some javascript to mesh the new data.

2)Are those strings you have posted representative of your "JSON", if so I don't believe it is well-formed. A comma-delimited set of sub-object would be an array, eg:
[{'person_id' : 1, 'first_name' : 'John', 'last_name' : 'Doe'}, ....]

EDIT: Regarding the information added in the comment, to handle CRUD operations like delete you can use the techniques outlined on the [DataTables blog](http://www.datatables.net/blog/Inline_editing).

Comment: 1) These columns are those that aren't related to data but actions. For example, lets say we have a column for each row that has delete button. That column is not related to data but it is there nevertheless


2) Just representation, not actual JSON

Comment: Then you have a couple of options, you could either add whatever you want to the data you are preparing to feed to DataTables (either on the DOM or in an array), or you could use one of the callback hooks offered by DataTables (like fnRowCallback or fnDrawCallback) to add it later. The second option would make much more sense semantically for things like "delete" buttons. As always, post more code, or even better, provide a link ;)